# training and test accuracy and step size

Tags: python, tensorflow

i'm running a code of tensorflow.On terminal it is giving me values of training and test accuracy and also step size. Can someone please explain these terms or provide any material that i can read to understand these terms and also stochastic gradient descent method for convolution neural networks

Comment: What's the purpose of your project ?

Comment: I want to use convolution neural network to train my network to detect a specific spin configuration.In code training step is 2000 and when i run this code it is is giving me values after every 100 step like this

Comment: step 0, training accuracy 0.5 test accuracy 0.500

Comment: I want to know what these training and test accuracy are telling me and also step size

Comment: I have to change filter size,batch size and no of filters and training step in the code to find out critical temperature of system.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have displayed in the terminal, you are using actually tflearn. This should also display the LOSS or COST which is, how far is your prediction from the actual output. Low loss and high accuracy  = better model.
The Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) allows learning rate decay. There is a good explanation here http://tflearn.org/optimizers/#stochastic-gradient-descent
In the menu on the felt side you find everything about Loss, Training, Accuracy, Layers etc.
And you can actually choose how often you want to display these things (I mean at what step).
As of batch size, learning rate, number of iterations, number of layers and number of nodes, you can play around with all these and see which works better for your dataset.

Comment: Ok i got the meaning of all these terms after reading about SGD method.Thanks for help

Comment: But what if i get 99% test accuracy after 2000 training steps and i still continue to train my network till 4000 training steps.Then my results show that after 2000 training steps sometimes test accuracy is 97% and sometimes even less than this value means it is changing.What does it indicate? @CrisH can you please explain this or suggest some topic or link to understand the reason behind this.

Comment: I think you should stop after 2000 steps. Maybe you don't have enough data for 4000. You have to prevent Overfitting. Did you also give test data to your network? That is also very important to see how the model is working. There are some good readings about Overfitting like http://machinelearningmastery.com/overfitting-and-underfitting-with-machine-learning-algorithms/ and also http://machinelearningmastery.com/a-simple-intuition-for-overfitting/ Hpe it helps! This is what I read for building my networks